# Random variable with defined density function in R

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with density function
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}
 x^{-2} &\text{if } x>1, \\ 
 0 &\text{if } x<1.
\end{cases} 
$$
Calculate $P(X>3 \mid X > 2)$.

I wonder if is possible to do it with *R* (the software package) and how I can do it.

Comment: By the way, X can have espected value, E{X}?

Comment: You can do it without using $R$. The result is 66.67%

Comment: Certainly the conditional probability can be found, but what do you mean by "do it with $\mathbb R$"? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think he means the programming language R. In this case your edit is not right.

Comment: @callculus you're right, I need to do it with the R programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have to use the Bayes theorem:

$$P(X> 3\mid X> 2)=\frac{P(X>3 \cap X>2) }{P(X>2)}=\frac{P(X>3 ) }{P(X>2)}$$

$$\frac{\int_3^{\infty} \frac1{x^2}\, dx }{\int_2^{\infty} \frac1{x^2}\, dx }=\frac{\left[ -\frac1x \right]_3^{\infty}}{\left[ -\frac1x \right]_2^{\infty}}=\frac{0-(-\frac13)}{0-(-\frac12)}=\frac{\frac13}{\frac12}=\frac23$$

If you want to use R then see [here](http://online.sfsu.edu/mbar/ECON312_files/Integrals.html) how to use it. For instance, the numerator in R is

```
f <- function(x) {1/x^2}

integrate(f, lower = 3, upper = Inf)
```